# Accessing first field of struct in a union of structs

Tags: c, struct, unions, memory-alignment, pointer-conversion

I have three structs that share the first type and name of the first field:

```
struct TYPEA {
  char *name;
  int x,y;   /*or whatever*/
};

struct TYPEB {
  char *name;
  float a[30]; /*or whatever*/
};

struct TYPEC {
  char *name;
  void *w,*z; /*or whatever*/
};
```

If I remember correctly the first field of a struct is required to start at the same address as the struct itself.

This makes me wonder if the same holds for a union:

```
union data {
  struct TYPEA;
  struct TYPEB;
  struct TYPEC;
};

union data *p = function_returning_a_sane_default_for_union_data();
printf("%s", (char*) p);
```

I have 2 question regarding this:

1. are unions required by standard 
   to always have their content at the same address?
2. would it work if the structs all had the same 
   fiels, so differing only in name?

Comment: There are no "common conventions" in C. If the standard does not guarantee something, it depends on the implementation or is UB. The standard indeed guarantees it. The actual uestion is: Why do you care at all? The cast is a bad idea. Use the first element. Better: move the common member to an embracing `struct`

Comment: @Olaf yeah, i think i was thinking about how specific implementations do it; but since i was interested in the standard i just removed it.
without it should be clearer, thank.

Comment: @Bathsheba: This is one of the few occasions I have to confess I downvoted in error. I first thought it was too broad (mostly because of the now removed part), but seeing your answer, After research for my own question, I think it is indeed quite a fine question. I changed the down- to an upvote now. Sorry for the err.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of a `struct` or `union` is guaranteed to have the same address-value as the `struct´/`union itself. Apparently it has not the same type!

For your usage, you do not need the cast and actually should avoid it:

> **6.5.2.3p6:** One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. …

So you **could** (see below) simply

```
printf("%s", p->name);
```

(Note: that your usage of unnamed `union` members is not standard compilant. It is a (very useful) gcc extension (`-fms-extensions`, at least also supported by MSVC, too).)

**But:** The code in your question is wrong. You have to name each union member or have the type declarator with each member. With the same first member, It will not weork, though, because the names of the mebers of such unnamed members have to be unique (how else are they supposed to be accesseed individually?). So this will not really work. What you **could** do is:

```
union data {
    struct TYPEA typea;
    struct TYPEB typeb;
    struct TYPEC typec;
};
```

and

```
printf("%s", p->typea.name);
```

even if the `struct` contains a value of `TYPEB` currently.

---

An alternative and more clear way, would be to wrap the `union` into a `struct`:

```
struct TypeA {
    int x,y;
};

...

struct data {
    char *name;
    union {
        struct TypeA;
        struct TypeB;
        struct TypeC;
    };
};
```

This also uses the gcc extension at two levels: for the outer `struct` and the `union`. As such, it requires unique names for all possible paths. If you want to be 100% compliant, name each member like above and use the full path on access.

Note: I removed the `name` member from the inner `struct`s in the `union` and moved it to the outer `struct`. I also changed names. The only well accepted naming convention in C is to use all-uppercase for macros only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; i'm still a beginner and i was trying to explore the type system :) might be unrelated but i find C type system really interesting; i first learnt C in my math bachelor then move to functional and dependent types languages and last i came back to C via Rust; it was a bit of an adventure but also really instructive.